# Sylius : Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Controller\ProductController::__construct()

Tags: sylius

I'm trying to override the ProductController,i've followed this docs :
http://docs.sylius.org/en/stable/bundles/general/overriding_controllers.html
 but an exception keep appearing:

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController::__construct() must implement interface Sylius\Component\Resource\Metadata\MetadataInterface, none given, called in C:\wamp3\www\sidratsoft_website\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1382 and defined

**AppBundle/Controller/ProductController.php:**

```
    <?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sylius\Component\Resource\Metadata\MetadataInterface;
use Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController;
use Sylius\Component\Resource\ResourceActions;


class ProductController extends ResourceController
{


public function allProdSpecificTaxonAction(Request $request,$t){

    $locale = $this->get('sylius.context.locale')->getLocale();
    /** @var Taxon $taxon */
    $taxon = $this->get('sylius.repository.taxon')
    ->findByName('Honeywell',$locale);
    var_dump($taxon);
    exit;
}
}
?>
```

**app/config/routing.yml:**

```
app_bundle_product:
path: /products/cat/{taxon}
defaults:
    _controller: AppBundle:Product:allProdSpecificTaxonAction
```

**app/config/config.yml:**

```
sylius_product:
resources:
    product:
        classes:
            controller: AppBundle\Controller\ProductController
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't have to register controller as service in `AppBundle/Resoures/config/services.yml`. As you extend `ResourceController` (which is totally correct) it has to have many dependency injected - fortunately , you don't have to inject them yourself, as *Sylius* will do the job and automatically register controller with dependencies injected.

Comment: yes i know but i posted the last try i've did, i can't know what could be the problem , is there a solution or an other way to override the product controller ?

Comment: This is for sure not a proper way to do that - according to reasons I've posted in my answer. Could you please provide info about error you get, when you remove service declaration in ``services.yml``?

Comment: its the same exception :
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController::__construct() must implement interface Sylius\Component\Resource\Metadata\MetadataInterface, none given, called in C:\wamp3\www\sidratsoft_website\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver.php on line 186 and defined

Answer (score 0):

i thiink i fixed it, the problem was in the _controller attribute in the routing :
from this :

```
app_bundle_product:
path: /products/cat/{taxon}
defaults:
    _controller: AppBundle:Product:allProdSpecificTaxonAction
```

to:

```
app_bundle_product:
    path: /products/cat/{taxon}
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.product:allProdSpecificTaxonAction
```